# p:fileUpload allowTypes regex

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl

with this regex /(.|/)(xml|xml.p7m)$/ accept xxxxx.xml, xxxx.xml.p7m but don't understand why accept xxxxx.xsl

```
            <p:fileUpload id="invoiceFileUploadId" widgetVar="invoiceFileUpload" fileUploadListener="#{menuController.uploadInvoice}" multiple="true"
            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xml|xml\.p7m)$/" label="#{label['upload']}" auto="true" dragDropSupport="true" process="@this" update="@this"
            invalidFileMessage="#{label['msg.fileNotValid']}" onstart="blockUI();" oncomplete="onCompleteUpload();"/>
```

Comment: Maybe in fact it does'nt accept, but just does'nt show the message. Try update="messages" (or whatever id is of your messages component)

Comment: messages updated correctly, infact if try xxxxx.aaa show message fileNotValid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the question is a bit old, but since in Primefaces 6.1 the issue still exists, I just investigated that a bit.

You use the following value for `allowTypes`:

```
/(\.|\/)(xml|xml\.p7m)$/
```

I digged into the Primefaces JavaScript code to find the location where the type is actually checked, and found the following (formatted for better readability):

```
if (this.cfg.allowTypes 
    && !(
        this.cfg.allowTypes.test(a.type) 
        || this.cfg.allowTypes.test(a.name))) { 
    /* type not allowed */ 
}
```

Hint: `a` is a `File`, having the properties `name` containing the file name and - more interesting - `type` containing the MIME type of the file (e.g. 'application/pdf').

The above PF code snippet shows that a file is only rejected, if neither its name nor its MIME type match the RegExp specified in `allowTypes`.

For XSL-files, the MIME-type can very well be `text/xml`, which matches the RegExp. The regular expression is interpreted in two totally different semantic contexts.

Side note: I always wondered why Primefaces documentation have the `(\.|\/)` part in the regular expression. My findings give me the impression that the `.` is for file extension matching, and the `/` is for MIME type matching. Who am I to judge?

### Update

As @kukeltje states in the comments: A regular expression like e.g. `/\.(xml|xml\.p7m)$/` would fix the problem. Or let's say "avoid the problem", as the real cause of the problem is that the regular expression is interpreted in two totally different contexts.

Comment: Your sidenote sounds correct. So `/\.(xml|xml\.p7m)$/` would solve it? Preventing something like `text/xml` to match? Maybe add this to your answer. Upvote from me!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I updated my answer accordingly!

Comment: suggest add this information `.` is for file name, `/` is for MIME-type on primefaces documentation. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you want xsl to work as well, use it like this.

```
allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xsl|xml|xml\.p7m)$/"
```

Comment: I do not want that xsl is accepted, but with the use regex that accepts it!
is inexplicable to me